# How to plot level-shifted sine wave in Python?

Tags: python, signal-processing

I am able to plot a simple sine wave but I was wondering how would I plot if it is a level-shifted sine wave? So, just to keep simple, please do refer to the picture attached to understand what I meant by 'level-shifted' sine wave?

[image]

That is all. Really needing help to get this to work for my project presentation. Thank you very much in advance.

Regards,
Anis

Comment: do you want to know the equation or the code? if its the equation, isnt it just y=sin(x) +1. if its code, what library are you using to plot it

Comment: Hi @Nish and welcome to Stack Overflow!  What object are you using to store the sine wave data in?  I.e. what data type.  What code are you currently using?

Comment: @TheBigKahuna omg you are so right. I am just over-complicating things. Thank you and cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as @TheBigKahuna mentions: it's a matter of simply adding 1

In terms of python [numpy](https://numpy.org/) and [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html) make this trivial:

```
import numpy as np
from math import sin,radians
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# calculate 360 samples
samples = np.array([sin(radians(angle)) for angle in range(0,360)])
# plot samples
plt.plot(samples)
plt.show()
```

[image: sine wave plot]

Numpy makes it trivial to simply add 1 to the data:

```
plt.plot(samples + 1)
plt.show()
```

[image: sine plot offset by +1]